# SWT: how to define my own Event types and listeners

Tags: swt

Any sample or tutorial links is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Creating Your Own Widgets using SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Writing%20Your%20Own%20Widget/Writing%20Your%20Own%20Widget.htm) will answer your question about custom events.